# Are the plants too close to the building?

Tags: exterior, green

Are these greens too close to the building or not? I heard different people say differnt things: some recommend 6 inches clearance between greens and the building; but some said it's ok to leave as it is now. Should I worry about these greens? The concern is that plants will hold the water near the building or attract insects, and thus damage the building in the long run

Another question: should I remove leaves on the ground and below the vines?

[image: building]

Comment: Are you in an area where anyone cares about wildfire?

Comment: you might want to clear it out now so that you can get to the hose come august.

Comment: @isherwood too close to the building. I am afraid the plants will hold the water near the building or attracts insects, and thus damage the building in the long run. I revised the question accordingly

Comment: @Harper I am in north Texas. I don't know whether leaves can be a hazard in the dry weather.

Comment: Have you ever heard of any  neighborhoods in your area being ravaged by chain fires that hop from building to foliage to building? Slurry bombers flying around dropping orange foam?  Does your fire department ever talk about "defendable space"? That last is the subject at hand, your local fire department would know for sure.

Comment: @Harper thanks for the advice. I will ask my local fire department.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your house had wood siding or other siding that allowed the vines to grow under it, then I would say keep it away. Since you have brick veneer, that will not be an issue, It may attach itself to your brick if it is a climbing vine, that would be the biggest issue other than the vent you have in the picture. The vine can grow into and through the screen mesh of the vent.

No need to remove the leaves unless it gets really deep. and it covers the vines.